# How to draw a circle within OxyPlot AngleAxis and MagnitudeAxis?

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

My plot model class is

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public PlotModel model { get; private set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        model = new PlotModel();
        AngleAxis a = new AngleAxis();
        a.Minimum = 0;
        a.Maximum = 360;
        MagnitudeAxis m = new MagnitudeAxis();
        m.Minimum = 0;
        m.Maximum = 1000;
        model.Axes.Add(a);
        model.Axes.Add(m);          
    }
}
```

And I want to draw just a simple circle of 500 radius.
So in my MainWindow class I put

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MyViewModel _myModel = new MyViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        oxpMyView.Model = _myModel.model;

        FunctionSeries f = new FunctionSeries((x) => 500, 0, 360, 0.1);
        oxpMyView.Model.Series.Add(f);
    }
```

But instead of circle, I see just a single line like this

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I draw circle properly within polar plot?

Answer (score 0):

hope you've already gotten solution. Otherwise, here is my solution:
You could use two functions constructor: (x)=>500 and (y)=>y